# Erroneously multiple values in MediaStore (when only one value is expected)

Tags: android, mediastore

It seems that the same Album is being split into multiple rows in the `MediaStore` if the tracks of the album are separated into multiple directories, and results in multiple rows with different values for the `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID` and `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_KEY` columns even though the tracks are all from the same Album (of the same artist).

For example, consider these file paths:

```
/mnt/sdcard/X/a.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/X/b.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/X/c.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/X/d.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Y/e.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Y/f.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Y/g.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Z/h.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Z/i.mp3
/mnt/sdcard/Z/j.mp3
```

Notice the mp3 files are separated by three different folders, "X", "Y", and "Z". The album title of all of the above tracks is the same; they are all from the same album by the same artist.

However, when I retrieve their data for `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID` and `MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_KEY`, I see three distinct groups that separate respectively to each of the folders. They all should return the same `ALBUM_ID` and `ALBUM_KEY`, but they don't. The `ALBUM_ID` and `ALBUM_KEY` for `a.mp3` are different from those of `e.mp3` and `h.mp3`, but are the same as those of `b.mp3`, `c.mp3` and `d.mp3`.

And only when I merge all of them into the same folder do they get updated to share the same `ALBUM_ID` and `ALBUM_KEY`.

Is this a bug or intentional design by Google?

Comment: I have just released a new version of Playlist Manager by TheoKlink on Google Play which has a query builder. Creating your own queries (playlists) may help to identify your issue. Alternatively, grab /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db, and explore the music records/database structure on your pc using an sql tool. I use RazorSQL. The only place where the pathname is held is in the _DATA field so as you state, I would not expect to see multiple ALBUM_ID

Comment: Just had a look at the album table. The ALBUM_KEY field is probably your problem. It holds unreadable information. Just use the ALBUM_ID and not ALBUM_KEY. ALBUM_KEY is different for each record

Comment: "The ALBUM_KEY field is probably your problem. It holds unreadable information. Just use the ALBUM_ID and not ALBUM_KEY. ALBUM_KEY is different for each record" - No, my findings show that ALBUM_ID is different as well if the album is split into multiple folders, as explained in the original post. In the example case given in the original post, there will be three distinct ALBUM_ID values for the same album.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the database:
select * from albums ORDER BY album ASC;
yes, multiple keys for albums which lead me to believe that the tagging may be incorrect. So I selected one album, Paolo Nuttine, Caustic Love, used Audiotagger to redo the tags, rescanned the device, pulled off the database and queried it usinf Razorsql. the table albums is still showing multiple keys for Caustic Love but album_info shows correctly. 
I also split another album across folders but did not see the behaviour described. 
Sorry that I was unable to shed light.